# Simplest Kubernetes cluster for a docker image

Tags: kubernetes

i have a docker image,  i need to create a Kubernetes cluster with one node.

don't have knowledge of Kubernetes, this is the first time I create it.

how can i do it with the simplest way?

Thanks

Comment: The [Getting started](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/) page in the Kubernetes documentation has several links.  I'd recommend reading through that documentation set in general, there's a lot of useful information and core concepts there.

Answer (score 0):

Plan A. For pure Kubernetes start with [minikube](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube):

`minikube start`

Plan B. For Openshift flavour of Kubernetes start with [OKD](https://www.okd.io/):

`oc cluster up`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to create a cluster using minikube.

Minikube can launch kubernetes locally , here is the official documentation , that explain how to do it: https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/learning-environment/minikube/

If this is just for learning purpose , you could also use the Playground in katacoda, it will spin up a cluster for you , and it's a great way to learn : https://www.katacoda.com/

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to take any udemy couses like "Kubernetes Certified Application Developer (CKAD) with Tests" which provide overall knowledge on Kubernetes with excellent animation with expert explanation for quick start.

In my opinion the understanding would be better with hands-on tests.